# Spring form handling, mapping an entity to form inputs

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Just looking at the petclinic sample application, and trying to learn form handling.

It seems the form maps to an entity 1:1 correct?  Is there any other configuration that has to be done, or will spring just know that all the form inputs map to the entity because that is what was added to the model in the GET request?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/owners/*/pets/{petId}/visits/new")
@SessionAttributes("visit")
public class AddVisitForm {

    private final Clinic clinic;


    @Autowired
    public AddVisitForm(Clinic clinic) {
        this.clinic = clinic;
    }

    @InitBinder
    public void setAllowedFields(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
        dataBinder.setDisallowedFields("id");
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String setupForm(@PathVariable("petId") int petId, Model model) {
        Pet pet = this.clinic.loadPet(petId);
        Visit visit = new Visit();
        pet.addVisit(visit);
        model.addAttribute("visit", visit);
        return "pets/visitForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processSubmit(@ModelAttribute("visit") Visit visit, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
        new VisitValidator().validate(visit, result);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "pets/visitForm";
        }
        else {
            this.clinic.storeVisit(visit);
            status.setComplete();
            return "redirect:/owners/" + visit.getPet().getOwner().getId();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the `@SessionAttributes` annotation on the class:

- When the original `GET` request comes, the newly created `Visit` is stored in a session.
- When the subsequent `POST` comes, object stored in the session is updated with the input values from the form.
- When `Visit` is finally persisted, `status.setComplete()` removes the session attribute.

Without `@SesssionAttributes`, `Visit` would be recreated using the form input values when `POST` comes.

Answer (score 0):

On the jsp you have to spring form tags and bind each variable to the modal attribute using the tags and also have to specify the modalattribute name in the form tag. [Tag ref](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/spring-form.tld.html)