# Spring MVC 3 - Binding parameters to backing object

Tags: java, validation, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to setup an edit form for my `User` object.  I have automatic binding from the form to the user object working fine.

I'm wondering how do I prevent malicious users from binding to fields of my `User` object that I don't want them to?

For example, my user object has `userName`, and it also has `points`.  When they click edit user, I want them to be able to change the `userName`, but not the `points`.  A malicious user could just send an extra `points=429429` as a hidden field in the form by editing the HTML, and this would automatically be bound to the backing object by Spring.

Comment: See your previous question, they do exactly this thing with `id` field using `@InitBinder`-annotated method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232095/spring-form-handling-mapping-an-entity-to-form-inputs

Comment: Good comment, the @initbinder thing is what I was looking for.  I would accept it as the answer if i could.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest separating your front-end code from the logic for what will be saved in the database.  The form backing object is just meant to be a simple object that captures want the user has done in the view... it shouldn't be used to save directly to the database.  I would have a Service layer handle the decision on whether or not to update certain fields... the controller should just receive the input and pass it along.  This way, the service can decide what fields should be updated.

```
public void updateUser(long userId, User updatedUser) {
    User currentUser = dao.getCurrentUserById(userId);
    currentUser.userName = updatedUser.username;
    //...... update anyother fields....
    dao.SaveUser(currentUser);
}
```

or you could define the method in a way that the caller knows what will be updated:

```
public void updateUser(long userId, String updatedUsername);
```

I would also argue that this is a lot easier to unit test if this logic is in the Service Layer.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your controller:

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
 binder.setAllowedFields("field1", "field2");
}
```